# START command in windows - the system cannot accept the start command parameter 1

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to call a batch file using `START` so I can control the processor affinity of the *single* compile command inside it.

**ATTEMPT #1**

```
START "" /NODE 1 /AFFINITY 0x1 build_one_qcc.bat
```

But I get the error message

> The system cannot accept the START command parameter 1

**ATTEMPT #2**

```
START "" build_one_qcc.bat
```

And that launched a new cmd window but within that window I got the same error message.

**ATTEMPT #3**

I copy-pasted to my command window the contents of the batch file plus the `START` command:

```
start "" /node 1 /affinity 0x1 "qcc -Vgcc_ntoarmv7le ... "
```

Still got same error

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`start /node 0 notepad.exe` works fine.
`start /node 1 notepad.exe` works fine **on a system with two physical processors**.

So what you were "doing wrong" was to run it on a single processor computer ;)

Each (physical) processor has it's "own" DIMM-slots (which doesn't mean, it has no access to the "other" memory - it's just a question of performance). You just can't assign memory that isn't there.

Comment: How do I set affinity to specific logical CORE?

Comment: Duh. Just include `/AFFINITY 1` without the `/NODE`

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the `1` of `/node 1` can't be processed.

It seems that the documentation for the `start` command is wrong for `[/NODE <NUMA-Node>]` or at least the format of a `NUMA-Node` isn't a number.

Why not use it without it?

```
START "" /AFFINITY 0x1 build_one_qcc.bat
```

Comment: not really wrong - just not complete. See my answer.